# Mobile Real Time Multiplayer SDKs

Tags: android, mobile, multiplayer

What are some good real time multiplayer SDKs I could use for Mobile game development?  More specifically for Android.  I am using LibGDX to make a simple multiplayer racing game and don't want to have to create a network interface from scratch.

I looked into Skiller but it seems somewhat dead.  Not much activity on the forums even though it seems very promising.

I also looked into Openfient but I don't think they support real time multiplayer anymore.  I remember they came out with Playtime but I think they stopped supporting it.

Considering I only need the actual racing aspect of the game being multiplayer, ie velocities, speeds, and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I am from Skiller team and although you can't see much activity in our forum we work very closely with our developers through emails and skype, so I can assure you we are totally active :)

If you need help or have any questions about any of our tools please send email to support@skiller-games.com and we will walk you through the integration. Besides our existing tools like social dashboard, leaderboards and turn based tools, next week we will release additional tools for our Android SDK with better code examples, personal challenges, real time tools and better user management.

By the way, we are always open for your suggestions so if there is something you are willing to see in our next SDK release please write to us.